# Cannot stat mv, file not found

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, mv

could somebody please help me find the problem with this code? getting this error "mv: cannot stat '~Desktop/RecyclingBin/testtest' : No such file or directory. It does exist and it is in the location ~Desktop/RecyclingBin/testtest

```
fileName=$1
fileLocation='cat ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/$fileName
if [ -z "$1" ]
   then
       echo "please enter a valid filename"
   else
       echo "do you want to restore?"
   read ans

   if [ "$ans" =="y" ]
   then 
       mv "~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/$fileName" "$fileLocation"
   fi
fi
```

Comment: You are quoting `~`, so it does not get expanded. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.22.2BAH4.22

Comment: yeah I've removed that so now I have mv ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/"$fileName" $fileLocation  but my $fileLocation is stored inside a text file with a tilde

Comment: Just say `fileLocation=~"/Desktop/RecyclingBin/logs/$fileName"
`

Comment: but im storing the cat of that file inside that variable since the text file contains the location I want to move the file to

Comment: If the path in the file contains `~` it won't expand if you quote it. Maybe you can say `fileLocation=$(cat ~/Desktop/.../$fileName)`

Answer (score 0):

The quotes prevent expansion of `~`. Put it outside the quotes:

```
mv ~/Desktop/RecyclingBin/"$fileName" "$fileLocation"
```

Comment: hmm the fileLocation also has a ~ it is stored in this format ~/Documents